# I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: asp.net, session, object-reference

I am getting the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error frequently even if I have tried increasing `Session Timeout = 1440` in the `web.config` file.

This happens on the `Session["company_id"]` because I am using this session again and again in most of the pages.

I know that the Session["company_id"] is getting expired but Is there a way to increase the time of expiration..?

Comment: May be the `Session["company_id"]` is null or empty i think, and you are trying to use it. Check the value of the session before you gonna use it.

Comment: Yes..that I can do but is there a way such that it may not expired for a long duration..

Comment: Check the Timeout duration from the start time and when ever its getting less than 10, regenerate the timeout by checking it through a seperate thread.

Comment: Can you implement it because I am not able to get it..?

Comment: Objects don't get expired from the session. Isn't the Session itself null? Did you disable the session for certain pages?

Comment: you are getting the error because the session is null and you are trying to use it.and i believe it might not be because of the timeout.you should be missing some thing in you'r code for sure.

Comment: what can it be for example..?@chamara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception will comes only when a null or empty object is tried to use. Inorder to make the session not to be expired for a long time, you should follow two steps.

1. Keep a continous eye on the Session Timeout.
2. Redirect the session when its about to expire.

The [Base Page for Detecting Sessions](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45300-base-page-for-detecting-session-timeout-in-aspnetc#/) will explain you every thing you need to do, please refer it once.